# Eclipse formatter : add blank line at the end of the class

Tags: java, eclipse, formatter

I am trying to setup my own profile for the Eclipse's code formatter but I cannot find a way to add a blank line at the end of the class.

```
public class MyClass {

     public void method() {
          // Something here.
     }
     // Want a blank line here.
}
```

[Here](http://paste.skyost.eu/view/aaa28c70) is my current profile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such option. The best you can do is set the number of empty lines to preserve and manually insert the blank line.

Comment: Like I said, manually insert the blank line(s) where you want them. The formatter has no option to insert empty lines at the end of methods or classes.

Answer (score 2):

In newer versions there is an option

```
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.blank_lines_after_last_class_body_declaration" value="1"/>
```

[Javadocs of eclipse formatter](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-12/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2Fformatter%2FDefaultCodeFormatterConstants.html)

[Bug issue in status "verify fixed"](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=169131)

Comment: But it's not support for groovy file